# Ajax Search of MySql table to create href link from result

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I currently have an Ajax search function that works and returns results.
However i am unable to get the search result to become a href link so that it adds the 'payroll_number' the search finds to the url to become candidatecard.php?pr=1388 for example. Where 1388 is the payroll number

```
    <a href="candidatecard.php?pr='.$Result['payroll_number'].'">
```

My web page code:

```
    <h2>Payroll <span>Number Search</span></h2>
                
                <!-- Search box. -->
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Payroll Number Search" />
    <b>Eg: </b><i>5100, 6237, 7259. </i>

    <!-- Suggestions will be displayed in below div. -->




     <?php
     echo "<a href='candidatecard.php?pr=$pn'>Search $pn</a>";
     ?>

     <div id="display"></div>
```

My js code

```
    //Getting value from "ajax.php".
    function fill(Value) {
    //Assigning value to "search" div in "search.php" file.
    $('#search').val(Value);
    //Hiding "display" div in "search.php" file.
    $('#display').hide();
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
    //On pressing a key on "Search box" in "search.php" file. This function will be called.
    $("#search").keyup(function() {
    //Assigning search box value to javascript variable payroll_numberd as "payroll_number".
    var payroll_number = $('#search').val();
    //Validating, if "payroll_number" is empty.
    if (payroll_number == "") {
       //Assigning empty value to "display" div in "search.php" file.
       $("#display").html("");
    }
    //If payroll_number is not empty.
   else {
       //AJAX is called.
       $.ajax({
           //AJAX type is "Post".
           type: "POST",
           //Data will be sent to "ajax.php".
           url: "ajax.php",
           //Data, that will be sent to "ajax.php".
           data: {
               //Assigning value of "payroll_number" into "search" variable.
               search: payroll_number
           },
           //If result found, this funtion will be called.
           success: function(html) {
               //Assigning result to "display" div in "search.php" file.
               $("#display").html(html).show();
           }
           });
           }
           });
           });
```

My Ajax code:

```
    <?php
    //Including Database configuration file.
    include "Include/db.php";
    //Getting value of "search" variable from "script.js".
    if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    //Search box value assigning to $payroll_number variable.
     $payroll_number = $_POST['search'];
   //Search query.
    $Query = "SELECT payroll_number FROM candidatedetails WHERE payroll_number LIKE 
  '%$payroll_number%' LIMIT 10";
   //Query execution
   $ExecQuery = MySQLi_query($con, $Query);
   //Creating unordered list to display result.
   echo '
   <ul>
   ';
   //Fetching result from database.
   while ($Result = MySQLi_fetch_array($ExecQuery)) {
   ?>
   <!-- Creating unordered list items.
    Calling javascript function named as "fill" found in "script.js" file.
    By passing fetched result as parameter. -->
    <li onclick='fill("<?php echo $Result['payroll_number']; ?>")'>
    <a>
     <!-- Assigning searched result in "Search box" in "search.php" file. -->
    <?php echo $Result['payroll_number'];?>
    </li></a>
    <!-- Assign searchbox result to pn variable.-->
    <?php$pn = $Result['payroll_number'];?>
    <!-- Closing parenthesis. -->
    <?php
    }}
    ?>
   </ul>
```

Comment: The single line of code in your first code snippet, demonstrating what you want to do, isn't present in your actual attempt...

Comment: In the PHP while loop at the end, where are you attempting to insert `payroll_number` in to the `<a>`'s href?

Comment: Hi David 
I thought I would show the working code and show what i am trying to achieve with the first code snippet. When i try and use the first code snippet it doesn't work

Comment: @Elkor: Can you perhaps show your attempt and indicate specifically how it "doesn't work"?  It could be as simple as a typo.  It's also not entirely clear to me what's going on in this "fill" function.  That's the function that invokes the AJAX operation, but it looks like the results of that AJAX operation are what call that function?  Can you clarify the specific steps your code is taking and where exactly it's failing?

Comment: Hi Chris G
I am trying to get the payroll number to become a link eg:

        candidatecard.php?pr=1388

Where 1388 is the payroll number search result.

Comment: Hi David, 
I have added the code that doesn't work. Many thanks

Comment: @Elkor: Well, this line of code is just one big syntax error: `$("#display").html(html).show()candidatecard.php? pr='.$Result[payroll_number'].';`  As well as a weird mix of JavaScript and PHP.  You can't use `$Result` in your client-side code, that's in your server-side code.  And JavaScript doesn't use `.` to concatenate strings, it uses `+`.  You claim that the AJAX operation already "works and returns results", what exactly are those results?  What exactly is in the `html` variable in the `success` callback of the AJAX operation?

Comment: I get that, I was asking you specifically how you attempted to create the `<a>`'s href in your AJAX code. In your JS code, the AJAX requests provides you with `<ul>...</ul>` text, so all you need to do is `$("#display").html(html);`

Comment: What you need to do in your PHP loop is: `<a href="candidatecard.php?pr=<?= $Result['payroll_number'] ?>">` or you can echo it: `<?php $pn = $Result['payroll_number']; echo "<a href='candidatecard.php?pr=$pn'>Search $pn</a>`

Comment: Hi @Chris, 
I have altered the page code using 
echo "<a href='candidatecard.php?pr=$pn'>Search $pn</a>";
and altered the Ajax code using 
 <!-- Assign searchbox result to pn variable.-->
   <?php$pn = $Result['payroll_number'];?>

When i mouse over the 'Search' href on the page it shows the active link to 
candidatecard.php?pr=

But the variable 'pn' is blank so the 
$pn = $Result['payroll_number']
in ajax is not being passed to the web page

Many thanks

Comment: `$pn` is a server-side variable I'm setting inside the loop that iterates over the DB results. I can now easily insert that variable into a double quoted string. I'm not sure why that variable is blank for you but I'm kind lost on how to help you here given how extremely basic this is. If you can't figure this out on your own, I'm not sure what to tell you at this point, sorry.